# QT creator paste in place?

Tags: qt

Is there anyway to accomplish a Copy -> Paste In Place with QT Creator?

I'm using a StackedWidget which has several pages, and many graphics/labels which need to be in the same place.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want. Can you explain a bit more using examples maybe?

Comment: I have a widget that contains several graphics, labels, fields etc that represent a single page of my interface.  When I make an additional page using the stacked widget, it creates a blank page.  I go back and copy everything from the first page, and paste it onto the second page. (maybe I only need to add a graphic or remove a label to make the second page different)

However, when I paste, it produces the copied items into a random place on the stage. I need it to paste them right where they were.

Comment: i guess this isnt possible with this software. Sucks

Comment: I'd settle for duplicate page....

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options here.

My **preferred** one would be to create an Ui class that you can freely design outside of your widget and then simply add it for example:

`ui->stackedWidget->addWidget( yourUiClassObject )`

---

I don't know why the copy pasting doesn't work for you, because for me it's doing it's job fine.

Make sure you copy everything inside the `QStackedWidget` at the same 
time.

Then remember that when you paste it, it'll create your selection where your mousepointer is the top left corner.

Don't undo the selection but instead drag it to the top left corner of the `QStackedWidget` where you got it from.

Now simply delete or make changes to your new page.

---

If that really doesn't work out for you, you can also put for example a `QFrame` around your UI elements and try to copy that to see if the objects inside stay at the same position, once you've dragged the whole container back to where it should start.

---

Now depending on how many pages we're talking, it can very much be a good option to create the interface by code.

---

First option I mentioned gives you the most freedom and cleaner code.

Comment: i do like the idea of making a class.   I've been pasting and then moving as you mentioned.

There should be an option to turn off pasting where the mouse is. I can't see a time where this is a good idea to NOT paste in place.  I'm sure it works for someone, but for me, it's a terrible design decision.

Comment: @bauervision if you point your mouse at the top left corner and paste you probably barely have to adjust it's positioning